# GoogleMock and GoogleTest in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, googletest, googlemock

Has anyone successfully built gmock and gtest in Visual Studio 2010? I've tried with version 1.5.0, but I only get incomprehensible compilation errors.

Comment: Without seeing the contents the errors there is not much people can do to help you.

Comment: Did you download and use CMake to generate solution files, then compile those? That worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: google test 1.6 worked flawlessly for me in Visual Studio 2010.  Maybe try 1.6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/googlemock/browse_thread/thread/c0a43cb290b2b691/45a5488beb99989f?lnk=gst&q=VS10#45a5488beb99989f) in google groups about issues found when building gmock-1.5.0 under VS2010. Following the thread, I've created a short readme file, which worked for me, so here it is:

- Download gmock 1.5.0 from [Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/).
- Extract to library folder on the machine (e.g. C:\Libs\gmock-1.5.0). From now on, this folder will be reffered as 'GMOCK_ROOT'.
- Open VS2010, and load the solution: GMOCK_ROOT\msvc\gmock.sln. Let VS convert it from VS2008 to VS2010.  **Important! DO NOT double-click the solution file under GMOCK_ROOT\msvc.** This resulted in a bad conversion.
- Perform the following changes to sources according to the [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/googlemock/browse_thread/thread/c0a43cb290b2b691/45a5488beb99989f?lnk=gst&q=VS10#45a5488beb99989f):

  - in project gmock --> Private Header Files --> gmock-internal-utils.h:

    - lines 201, 202: comment out the 'Helper' functions:

    `char Helper(To);`

    `static char (&Helper(...))[2];  // NOLINT`

    - lines 210-219: replace the entire `#ifdef..#endif` section with:

    `static const bool value = std::is_convertible<From, To>::value;`
  - in project gmock_test --> Source Files --> gmock-printers_test.cc, line 848:
    perform an explicit casting of the NULL argument to `void*`, otherwise VS will automatically regard it is a null int. The resulting line should look like this:

    `t10(false, 'a', 3, 4, 5, 1.5F, -2.5, str, static_cast<void*>(NULL), "10");`

    5. Build the solution. This should result in 4 warnings, which, as described below, are (probably) OK.

Hope this helps,

Boaz

---

VS2010 compiler warnings from step 5 (see remarks at the end):

> Warning   1   warning C4996:
>   'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with
>   parameters that may be unsafe - this
>   call relies on the caller to check
>   that the passed values are correct. To
>   disable this warning, use
>   -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++
>   'Checked Iterators'   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\xutility  2227    1
>
> Warning   2   warning C4996:
>   'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with
>   parameters that may be unsafe - this
>   call relies on the caller to check
>   that the passed values are correct. To
>   disable this warning, use
>   -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++
>   'Checked Iterators'   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\xutility  2227    1
>
> Warning   4   warning C4413:
>   'std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Car,_Cdr>::_Value'
>   : reference member is initialized to a
>   temporary that doesn't persist after
>   the constructor exits C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\tuple 137 1
>
> Warning   3   warning C4373:
>   'testing::gmock_generated_function_mockers_test::MockFoo::TakesConst':
>   virtual function overrides
>   'testing::gmock_generated_function_mockers_test::FooInterface::TakesConst',
>   previous versions of the compiler did
>   not override when parameters only
>   differed by const/volatile
>   qualifiers    C:\Libs\gmock-1.5.0\test\gmock-generated-function-mockers_test.cc   133 1

Remarks regarding warnings:

1. Warnings 1,2 are about Copy() in xutility being deprecated due to safty. As the mock library is not a part of the production release, this is OK by me.
2. Warning 4 is OK according to the [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/googlemock/browse_thread/thread/c0a43cb290b2b691/45a5488beb99989f?lnk=gst&q=VS10#45a5488beb99989f).
3. Warning 3: not sure, but all seems to work well.

Comment: re your 4th step, when you wrote lines 210-221, I think you actually meant from #ifdef _MSC_VER   to   #endif  // _MSV_VER    (inclusive) indeed in the vicinity of these lines.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone has a problem building the gmock solution itself, that is can’t generate the .lib files, this did it for me (vs 2015):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlemock/FaEAHedxpAQ

> gmock_config.props contains an outdated definition of GTestDir:
>   `<GTestDir>../../gtest</GTestDir>`
>
> Replace it with `<GTestDir>../../../googletest</GTestDir>` and you
>   should get past your error.

At least the libs were compiled, i still got the gmock_test error though, despite the change suggested there.