# What libraries do I need to link to build a googlemock example?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm able to compile googlemock v1.6.x in VS2010 and produce both release and debug libraries. In other words, the issue I have is NOT this [GoogleMock and GoogleTest in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141835/googlemock-and-googletest-in-visual-studio-2010)

Now I'm following the example here http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies, and I'm having these errors. I did link the generated *.lib files and added the correct library directory in VS2010. So what else do I need to link?

```
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > *)" (??0?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@PAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@@Z) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??0?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAE@XZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::gptr(void)const " (?gptr@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setg(char *,char *,char *)" (?setg@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXPAD00@Z) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setp(char *,char *)" (?setp@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXPAD0@Z) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::eback(void)const " (?eback@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Pninc(void)" (?_Pninc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEPADXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setp(char *,char *,char *)" (?setp@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXPAD00@Z) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::pbase(void)const " (?pbase@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::epptr(void)const " (?epptr@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::pptr(void)const " (?pptr@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::gbump(int)" (?gbump@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXH@Z) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::egptr(void)const " (?egptr@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IBEPADXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::pbump(int)" (?pbump@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXH@Z) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??0?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAE@XZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: struct std::_Iterator_base12 * * __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Getpfirst(void)const " (?_Getpfirst@_Container_base12@std@@QBEPAPAU_Iterator_base12@2@XZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(__int64)" (?width@ios_base@std@@QAE_J_J@Z) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,__int64)" (?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE_JPBD_J@Z) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputc(char)" (?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHD@Z) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::rdbuf(void)const " (?rdbuf@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::fill(void)const " (?fill@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEDXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::flags(void)const " (?flags@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (?width@ios_base@std@@QBE_JXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void)" (?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@XZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::tie(void)const " (?tie@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall std::ios_base::good(void)const " (?good@ios_base@std@@QBE_NXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(unsigned int)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@I@Z) already defined in gmockd.lib(gtest-all.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::locale::facet * __thiscall std::locale::facet::_Decref(void)" (?_Decref@facet@locale@std@@QAEPAV123@XZ) already defined in gmockd.lib(gmock-all.obj)
1>libcpmtd.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Ios_base_dtor(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Ios_base_dtor@ios_base@std@@CAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Addstd(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Addstd@ios_base@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::locale::facet::_Facet_Register(class std::locale::facet *)" (?_Facet_Register@facet@locale@std@@CAXPAV123@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Getgloballocale(void)" (?_Getgloballocale@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Init(void)" (?_Init@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_ctor(class std::_Locinfo *,char const *)" (?_Locinfo_ctor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@PBD@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_dtor(class std::_Locinfo *)" (?_Locinfo_dtor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj) : error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(setlocal.obj) : error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __free_dbg already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtSetCheckCount already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(osfinfo.obj) : error LNK2005: __open_osfhandle already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dosmap.obj) : error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(fflush.obj) : error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(lconv.obj) : error LNK2005: _localeconv already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbghook.obj) : error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winxfltr.obj) : error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(hooks.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj) : error LNK2005: _sprintf_s already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(tolower.obj) : error LNK2005: _tolower already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(strtol.obj) : error LNK2005: _strtol already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(strtoq.obj) : error LNK2005: __strtoui64 already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrptw.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtDbgReportW already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(vsnprnc.obj) : error LNK2005: __vsnprintf_s already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(printf.obj) : error LNK2005: _printf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(vprintf.obj) : error LNK2005: _vprintf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Documents and Settings\fouts\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\GMockTest\Debug\GMockTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This looks like you've got a mismatch in your choice of C Runtime and C++ Standard Libraries.

You can choose between the static (.lib) or shared (DLL) versions of these using the compiler switches `/MT`, `/MTd`, `/MD` or `/MDd`.  `MT` variants indicate the static libraries, and `MD` the shared.  The `d` appendix indicates the debug versions of each.

These can be set in Visual Studio by going to Project => Properties => Configuration Properties => C/C++ => Code Generation => Runtime Library

The problem appears to be that your project uses `/MD` and `/MDd`, but that GMock and Gtest were built with `/MT` and `/MTd`.  You need to recompile GMock/Gtest with the `/MD` and `/MDd` flags, or change yours to `/MT` and `/MTd`.

Comment: That was EXACTLY the problem! Thanks! What keyed you in from the link errors?

Comment: @ChrisF Hours spent debugging similar linker errors :-)  The giveaway is the linker complaining about Standard Library functions (any function in `std::` namespace) being already defined.  Normally the only way to get that is to try to link 2 different copies of the CRT library.  This could be as in your case using mismatched static/shared, or it could also be a mismatch between debug/release.  The various incarnations of the MS CRT libs are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140584).

Answer (score 0):

you can build Gmock as dll and use it (this is for 1.7 don't know if it works on 1.6)
Set preprocessor flag (properties->c/c++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions) GTEST_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY to build the Gmock as dll, and build the dll that consumes gmock with GTEST_LINKED_AS_SHARED_LIBRARY

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Consider editing it to make it more readable.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem:
Solution:
Release version
Properties: configuration properties>c/c++>General>Warning level>level4(/W4)
Properties: configuration properties>code generation>runtime library : multi-threaded(/Mt)
Properties: configuration properties>Precompiles header:Not using precompiled headers

Debug version
Properties: configuration properties>c/c++>General>Warning level>level4(/W4)
Properties: configuration properties>code generation>runtime library : multi-threaded(/MTd)
Properties: configuration properties>Precompiles header:Not using precompiled headers